# How to get ASP.NET MembershipUser by email

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

How can I retreive an ASP.NET MembershipUser by supplying the email address, none of the overloads of `Membership.GetUser()` take email address.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
string thisUser= Membership.GetUserNameByEmail("email")
```

should do the trick, Then you can use

```
 MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser(thisUser);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Membership.GetUserNameByEmail method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.getusernamebyemail.aspx). Hopefully that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "GetUserNameByEmail" method. Here is an example: [MSDN Help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.getusernamebyemail.aspx)